# Which of those courses can get me to Theoretical Physics?

Tags: mathematical-physics

Im going to start a master of Maths in September and I would like some day **to work in particle labs, trying to understand equations of nature** etc

I know which branches of maths I have liked so far (algebra, analysis, groups etc) and those that I didn't so much (geometry) but Im not sure if it means anything (e.g if I didn't like undergrad geometry will I not like algebraic geometry too because it has the word geometry in it or is it really different ?)

We will have to pick courses and Im not sure which ones will become "requirements" later or not. Here is a list of courses offered.

- differential topology/geometry
- stochastic processes
- Lie groups
- algebraic geometry
- ergodic theory
- spectral operators
- algebraic surfaces
- dynamic systems
- Galois theoery
- number theory
- homologic algebra
- cohomology
- Hurwitz theory
- Hodge theory

**From this list, which courses look important for maths/physics later? **

Note: I was accepted to two masters and I have to pick one, and lots of courses are offered here but not there and vice versa. Also I have looked up those on internet but if someone has real insight it is better. Lastly, Im doing this in addition to my job, Im not at uni anymore and my access to ask teachers some questions is limited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer.

For particle physics you'll certainly need Lie groups (and their representations). You'll also need partial differential equations (not on your list) and operator theory.

You (probably) won't need number theory, or algebraic geometry (but who knows for sure).

Since you need this information as part of your decision about which school to attend, please edit your question to show which courses are available at school A but not B, and vice verse. For courses common to both schools you can postpone deciding whether to take them until you get there.

Finally, this might be a better question on physics stackexchange.